Update field meta of dynamic object in mappings using NEST
I have a nested field with dynamic=true as below. I keep the tr/en localizations of the fields in meta. How can I add the meta when adding a new field due to dynamic mapping in a new insert request?
{
    "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "meta": {
                "en": "Time",
                "tr": "Zaman"
            }
        },
        "applicationName": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                }
            },
            "meta": {
                "en": "Application Name",
                "tr": "Uygulama Adi"
            }
        },
        "data": {
            "dynamic": "true",
            "properties": {
                "deviceId": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

